# Initialise struct array with a 1d array

Tags: c, casting

I have a constant array that comes from a define that I cannot modify.

```
#define MY_ARRAY {1,11,111,2,22,222,3,33,333}
#define SIZE 3
```

I want to assign this array to a const struct array

```
// EDIT : Added mixed sizes to show there might be a padding problem as well
struct foo {
    uint8_t val1; 
    uint32_t val2;
    uint32_t val3;
}

const struct foo my_foo[SIZE] = MY_ARRAY;
```

But my compiler complains about missing braces around initializer. It expects something alongs the lines of :

```
const struct foo my_foo[SIZE] = {{1,11,111},{2,22,222},{3,33,333}};
```

I would need some kind of typecast but I can't make it work

I tried this :

```
const struct foo my_foo[SIZE] = (const struct foo[SIZE]) MY_ARRAY;
```

But I get the same warning

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you could probably use a pointer cast:

```c
const int[SIZE * 3] numbers = MY_ARRAY;
const struct foo my_foo[SIZE] = *(*my_foo[])&numbers;
```

Comment: This does not work https://godbolt.org/z/vaoE9781a

Comment: this is probably undefined behaviour because the `struct foo` has very likely a padding word so that `sizeof numbers != sizeof my_foo`

Comment: my real struct does contain mixed types so padding might be a problem yeah

Comment: @ensc It would also be a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and UB for that reason, too.